Why the WiFi works only with USB WiFi dongle, not with the laptop on-board WiFi?
I have a Fritzbox wifi router, and the wifi network name never(almost) shows up in the laptop. So I mostly use LAN cable. Very rarely, I have been able to connect to the wifi network with my laptop(probably twice in this year). It is extremely random. I tried changing the wifi channel in router to something less than 11, and it did not work. Also, I checked that the router is not blacklisting my laptop. I can connect to other WiFi networks, but not with fritzbox routers.
However, I can connect to the same wifi network, if I use a wifi dongle. Why is that the case? And how can I use my on-board laptop wifi?
Some of the device details using ifconfig:
Laptop:
Centrino Wireless-N 2230
logical name: wlp2s0
version: c4
width: 64 bits
clock: 33MHz
capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.4.0-150-generic firmware=18.168.6.1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
Wifi-dongle: LogiLink Wireless N150
logical name: wlx7cdd90913071
capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rt2800usb driverversion=5.4.0-150-generic firmware=0.36 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11

In the Fritzbox, there are settings for Wi-Fi standards like g, n, or ac. Take a look there. I forgot where exactly it was, but I had the same issue with a device before in the past.

Your issue with connecting to the Wi-Fi could be the fact that your device supports a specific Wi-Fi standard that isn't activated on your Fritzbox.
The Fritzbox can use several Wi-Fi standards like 802.11g (older and slower), 802.11n (faster and common), or 802.11ac (very fast, only for 5 GHz).
If your device only supports 802.11g but the Fritzbox is set to n or ac only, it won't be able to connect.
Check and try:
Log in Fritzbox an goo to the Wi-Fi settings and look for the section where you can select the Wi-Fi standards.
Make sure that the standards your device supports (g or n) are enabled, try and check what works.
After that, restart both your device and the Fritzbox, and try to connect again.
Unstable and slow Internet Intel Centrino Wireless-N 2230
Wireless device cannot connect to the FRITZ!Box

The internal adapter uses the iwlwifi driver, which could have compatibility problems with certain routers or configurations, especially older Wi-Fi adapters like yours.

Power management features can interfere with Wi-Fi connections. Try disabling power management for your Wi-Fi adapter:
sudo iwconfig wlp2s0 power off
Check this post to:
WiFi Power Management Keeps Turning On

Under WiFi-->WiFi Channel, there exists a section to select "Wi-Fi 6" or "Wi-Fi 4" as WiFi standard. Would it be sufficient only to set "Wifi 4" for 2.4-GHz frequency band?

Just to add another reason that I once had for no working wifi:
Check what kind(s) ofn safety protocol your router is using. And check the configuration of your wifi connection in your OS (you didn't specify, but most desktop systems have a graphical configuration for this). For example I have a university wireless network that uses WPA2 Enterprise. Which when I first tried I think Manjaro with Wayland that just wasn't supported, but I spend a lot of time trying to fix it.  If something like that is the case you may be able to switch either what protocol your router uses (e.g. WPA2 Personal, also maybe the authentification e.g. MSCHAPv2, wich is the one used by my universities network) or be able to switch what your laptop tries to connect itself with (in the connectivity settings of your OS).
